# How to create custom sql query on category listing page in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop 1.7 i want to modify the default SQL query of the listing products on the category page.
I cant found which SQL query returning products on category page.

there is custom fields added to product table priority(1,2,3) and state (0,1)

so need to display products above matching columns using custom SQL query

Answer (score 1):

check **classes/Category.php**

the getProducts() method is the one responsible of returning products result. You could override it to suit your needs.

Beware that there are two main queries inside the method , first one is for product count pagination, other is for actual getting products data.

Comment: i have checked and try to add exit inside getProducts and its seems this function is not used on category page. When we enable faceted search module then  class Category.php getProducts() is not called. yes When we disable faceted search module then getProducts() function is called. It seems in 1.7 when faceted module is enabled then its not allow us to call getProducts() . Please if you know how to modify query when faceted search module is enabled then let me know. Will really appreciate for this help

Comment: @PankajKumar Update the question post and add description of the used module